# Wouldn't a while loop with an init statement be useful?

Tags: c++

I know that a `while` loop can easily be replaced by a `for` loop, if you need to initialize a variable once, e.g.

```cpp
auto item = first();
while (!item.is_last()) {
    foo(item);
    item = next();
}
```

can be written as

```cpp
for (auto item = first(); !item.is_last(); item = next()) {
    foo(item);
}
```

But what if you want to initialize some variable in *every* iteration? The variable could be defined before the loop and reassigned within the loop:

```cpp
auto remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now();
while (remaining.count() > 0) {
    foo(remaining);
    remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now();
}
```

Of course this could become a `for` loop, too:

```cpp
for (auto remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now(); remaining.count() > 0; remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {
    foo(remaining);
}
```

But quite some code gets duplicated.

Another option is to declare the variable outside the loop:

```cpp
std::chrono::system_clock::duration remaining;
while (remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now(), remaining.count() > 0) {
    foo(remaining);
}
```

But then we cannot use `auto`, which is really useful, if the exact type isn't important, like in this little example.

Ideally I'd prefer something like this:

```cpp
while (auto remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now(); remaining.count() > 0) {
    foo(remaining);
}
```

But C++ doesn't offer such a `while` loop with init statement for each iteration. Maybe it would be too confusing, as people would not know when exactly this initialization would happen (just once, or for each iteration).

Any other ideas? What's the best way to express the intent to reassign some value to a variable *before* evaluating said variable in a loop?

Comment: "*Another option is to declare the variable outside the loop:*" This is a bad choice. If the variable only applies within the loop, then defining it inside the for-loop is the appropriate choice, which makes the variable invisible outside the loop and less error-prone.

Comment: If you want to **initialize** an object each time through the loop you cannot define the variable outside the loop. It gets initialized where it's defined; to initialize it each time through the loop it would have to be defined inside the loop.

Comment: An init-statement is only done once.  If an init-statement `while` was added to the language, I'm pretty sure the init-statement would only occur once.  There are other ways in the language to express "init on every loop iteration".  There are also ways in the language to hide that detail to make the callsite cleaner.

Comment: "*Another option is to declare the variable outside the loop... But then we cannot use `auto`, which is really useful, if the exact type isn't important, like in this little example*" - You could use a lambda to calculate the time, and then use `decltype` to declare the `remaining` variable the same type the lambda returns, eg: `auto get_remaining = [&](){ return deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now(); }; decltype(get_remaining()) remaining; while (remaining = get_remaining(), remaining.count() > 0) { foo(remaining); }` ([demo](https://onlinegdb.com/_dlXrODUu))

Comment: @康桓瑋 "*If the variable only applies within the loop, then defining it inside the for-loop ... makes the variable invisible outside the loop and less error-prone*" - you could always just wrap the loop inside a new scope block. Then you can declare the variable outside the loop but still hide it from surrounding scopes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a infinite loop with a break:

```
while (true) {
    auto remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    if (remaining.count() <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @MikeVine Good point, fixed. Admittedly, I wasn't paying much attention to how `std::chrono` was being used, and ran away with the assumption that a member function named `count` would return a non-negative integer.

Comment: This looks like the best approach, as the variable applies within the loop only, `auto` can be used nicely, and the expression is not repeated. So I accepted this answer. Still it feels a bit like a workaround, since the condition (and break) is in the middle of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your "declare the variable outside the loop" case can be written with `for` with it declared inside the loop.

```
for (std::chrono::system_clock::duration remaining; remaining = deadline - std::chrono::system_clock::now(), remaining.count() > 0;) {
    foo(remaining);
}
```

> Maybe it would be too confusing, as people would not know when exactly this initialization would happen (just once, or for each iteration).

Yes, I'd be very surprised by an initialiser running every iteration of the loop, and not once like *every other* initialiser.